# Primefaces LazyDataModel produces different output local than on remote server

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem where I use Primefaces 4.0 on wildfly8 (jboss 8) server.

I have the same server locally with the same settings than a remote server where the app would be deployed in production.

When I deploy the app to remote server the p:dataTable are empty. Only the tables that uses primefaces LazyDataModel are empty.

There is no error in log.

I have also tried to deploy the maven build ear that I deploy to remote server also on a local server and locally is working as it should. Obviously there is some difference on the remote server but I can not see what it could be, the standalone.xml are the same locally and remotely

Any hints what could cause this strange behaviour?

I have put some prints to see what is happening in the code and in the count method I get 4520 returned, so the SQL is working ok the problem is that in the xhtml if I put `#{billsBean.billsData.rowCount}` just before the table where the data should be I get 0. On the local machine for the same view and the same code I get 4520

So it looks like the data gets lost somewhere in the rendering of the table.

```
@Named
@Stateless
public class LazyBillsDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Bill> implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -6488655263171321725L;

@Inject
@DomainsDB
private EntityManager em;

@EJB
BillHandler billHandler;

@Inject private Logger log;

public LazyBillsDataModel() {
    super();
}

@Override
public List<Bill> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>> enetering load data for BILLS");
    log.debug(">>>>>>>> enetering load data for BILLS");

    if (sortField == null || sortField.equals("")) {
        sortField = "bill.dateCreate";
    }

    List<Bill> data = selectData(first, pageSize, sortField, DataUtilsWeb.transformSortOrder(sortOrder), filters);
    // row count
    this.setRowCount(count(filters));

    return data;
}

private int count(Map<String, String> filters) {
    String hql = "select count(bill.idBill) from Bill bill ";
    if (filters != null && filters.size() > 0) {
        hql += " where " + prepereWhereFilters(filters);
    }

    Query query = em.createQuery(hql);
    fillQueryWitkFilterData(query, filters);

    System.out.println(">>>>>>>> count " + ((Long) query.getSingleResult()).intValue());

    return ((Long) query.getSingleResult()).intValue();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List<Bill> selectData(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {

    List<Bill> data = new ArrayList<Bill>();

    String hql = "select bill from Bill bill left join fetch bill.organization left join fetch bill.billType left join fetch bill.billStatus ";

    if (filters != null && filters.size() > 0) {
        hql += " where " + prepereWhereFilters(filters);
    }

    // sorting
    if (sortField != null && !sortField.equals("")) {
        hql += " order by " + sortField;
        if (sortOrder != null && !sortOrder.equals("")) {
            hql += " " + sortOrder;
        }
    }

    Query query = em.createQuery(hql);
    fillQueryWitkFilterData(query, filters);

    // define query boundaries
    query.setFirstResult(first);
    query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    data = (List<Bill>) query.getResultList();

    System.out.println(">>>>>>>> BILLS laoded num : " + data.size());
    log.debug(">>>>>>>> BILLS laoded num : " + data.size());

    return data;
}

 ......
 }
```

Comment: Make sure both are pointing to same database.

Comment: @Makky of course they are pointing to the same database. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue

It looks like the standalone.xml have changed in the wildfly 8.0 FINAL release, localy I had the 8.0 FINAL from 20.2.2014 and on server I had 8.0 FINAL from 18.4.2014

And after comparing the standalone.xml from both servers they differed

So i started merging them and I fout that this part wass missing from ejb3 subsystem

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:2.0>

  <stateless>
       <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
  </stateless>
```

not shure what this flag does but after inserting this text the primfaces table apeared full of data.